# Dynamically ingesting list of schemas to query in dbt using jinja

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am building a data pipeline that ingests data from several schemas. I am trying to use jinja to ingest a list of schema names, and then queries specific columns in a table (with the identical name) in all these schemas before combining data into a single staging table.

On a conceptual level, I know that I need to create two lists with Jinja: a list with the `schema` names that I want to loop over, and a list of the column names that I want to query in the table that exists in all of schemas I am querying. Let's call the list of schema names `schema_names` and the list of column names `column_names`.

- `{% set var schema_names=('brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3') %}`
- `{% set var column_names=('col1', 'col2', 'col3') %}`

Theoretically, the next step seems to be that I should pass these values via Jinja into a query that selects the same list of columns from tables within the schemas in `schema_vars`. Were I to write the SQL query manually, I would use several `WITH` statements that were then combined using a `UNION ALL`:

```
/* Query that creates a variable with value `brand1` while querying `brand1` schema */
WITH schema1_data
       AS (
            SELECT 'brand1' AS schema_name,
                   col1,
                   col2,
                   col3
            FROM brand1.table_name
  ),

/* Query that creates a variable with value `brand2` while querying `brand2` schema */
     schema2_data
       AS (
            SELECT 'brand2' AS schema_name,
                   col1,
                   col2,
                   col3
            FROM brand2.table_name
     ),

  /* Query that creates a variable with value `brand3` while querying `brand3` schema */
     schema3_data
       AS (
            SELECT 'brand3' AS schema_name,
                   col1,
                   col2,
                   col3
            FROM brand3.table_name
     ),
  /* Union statement combining identical tables from 3 schemas */
     combined_schemas
       AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM schema1_data
            UNION ALL
            (
              SELECT *
              FROM schema2_data)
            UNION ALL
            (
              SELECT *
              FROM schema3_data)
     )

SELECT *
FROM combined_schemas
```

Thoughts on how this would be best implemented in Jinja/dbt? Also open to alternative framings of the problem that take a different approach to combine information from identical tables in different schemas into a single staging table to be processed by a data pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UNION ALL approach sounds good. You can simplify your plan a little bit: if the columns you want from each models are the same, then you don't need the `column_names` variable. Also, using CTEs only helps if you would write this manually, but with a jinja template, it actually makes your life harder so do not force yourself to use them.

You will need:

- a `jinja` for loop which is documented [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for).
- the `loop.last` special variable to access within the for loop block

I have not tested the following code but here is how I would write this:

```sql
{% set var schema_names=('brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3') %}
{% for schema in schema_names %}
(
  select
    '{{ schema }}' as schema_name,
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
  from {{ schema }}.table_name
)
{% if not loop.last %}
union all
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't want to code this yourself, `dbt_utils` has this functionality already implemented: [`union_relations`](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-utils/tree/master#union_relations-source).

Although, it will be interesting for you to reference against their implementation (more complicated than what you need because they handle more corner cases) which you can find [here](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-utils/blob/master/macros/sql/union.sql#L60-L82).

Comment: Tiny edit: `{{ schema }} as schema_name` needs to be ` '{{ schema }}' as schema_name` in order to not throw an error, but otherwise this works perfectly!